# iterate over tables in a word document using python docx

Tags: python, ms-word, docx

I have been trying to figure out how to add cell 0 from all tables  in a word document to my_list , I managed to add from a specific table placement number (96) but can't seem to pull all tables data, I used this for table array number 96 and it worked

```
`tables = list(d.tables)
tbl = d.tables[96]
my_list = []
for rw in tbl.rows:
    my_list.append(rw.cells[0].text)

print(my_list)
```

tried a lot of different options to iterate all tables and add to my_list, one being below but it gives the error 
'Table' object has no attribute 'cells'

```
my_list = []

tbl = list(d.tables)
for val in tbl:
    for rw in tbl:
        my_list.append(rw.cells[0].text)


print(my_list)
```

any help is greatly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete runnable example so I cannot verify it, but:

This part is Bad Python:

```
for val in tbl:
    for rw in tbl:
```

You are iterating over `tbl` twice, and all the outer loop is doing is running the inner loop `len(tbl)` times. The second line might be

```
for rw in val:
```

but I am not 100% on that due to Not Enough Information.

(Also, consider renaming both `tbl` and `val` to something resembling what they contain: `list_of_tables` and `a_table` would be far better. Also, use `row` instead of `rw`, as Python does not have some unreasonable variable name length width.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your recommendation, it led me down the right path,  i just added .rows and it worked.             for table in tables:
                                         for row in table.rows: